# Error 9003 Log Scan is Invalid Error When Restoring Transaction Log After SQL2016 SP2 + CU8 Upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction-log

We are using SQL 2016 Enterprise Edition and have recently applied SP2 + CU8.  We were previously on SP1 + CU6.  Since the update we are getting the following error when restoring transaction logs on our DR server.

> The log scan number (20913:512:1) passed to log scan in database '' is
>   not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log
>   file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error
>   occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise,
>   restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during
>   startup.

The log restore succeeds if NORECOVERY is used and then later logs are applied successfully with STANDBY.  But if the file that causes the error is applied with STANDBY future log restores fail when using either NORECOVERY or STANDBY.  The only fix we have found is to do a full restore.

Is there any other workaround other than a full restore?

The frequency of the error is 2 times a day on 3 different databases.  The log backups originated from an AlwaysOn secondary server.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug that had been re-introduced with one of the recent CU's.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/940126/fix-error-9003-is-logged-in-the-sql-server-error-log-file-when-you-use

Comment: We have changed our backup to take the log backups on the Primary Always On replica as a workaround to this issue.

Also looking to uninstall CU8.

Comment: Uninstalling CU8 did not fix the issue.